# Are Zombies in the Walking Dead flammable?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Sometimes zombies are flammable, while other times they are not at all (since they are a big squishy wet blob). Have the zombies in The Walking Dead been shown to be more or less flammable as a living human?

Comment: Umm... if I asked you why you want to know, would I regret it?

Comment: Are you talking about the TV series or the comic? In the case of the TV series, with very few episodes, it's just a case of watching them to see if they show one thing or the opposite...

Comment: With a hot enough fire, anything will burn.  The human body contains large amounts of fat (depending, of course, on the individual's level of health) which can lead to the [Human Wick Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_effect)

Comment: @Beta Probably. Check out the quote on Jack's profile page ;-)

Comment: Related, possible dupe of [Why do fried zombies live in The Walking Dead?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106653/why-do-fried-zombies-live-in-the-walking-dead)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear they burn just as well as normal folk. I put the reasonsing for this in the following spoiler box.

> When the camp is attacked in the first season (I believe somewhere around episode 3-5), they later burn the "dead". Glenn makes a point that their vicitms (i.e. the dead *humans*) will not be burnt but instead buried. This indicates that the now-dead undead (to avoid use of the word "zombie") burn equally well as a living human being.

Answer (score 3):

Re: TV series - In the final episode of Season 2 ("Beside the Dying Fire"), the following incident occurs:

> Rick and Carl lock themselves in the barn to create temporary safety from the walkers pursuing them, and then decide to douse the floor with petrol, get themselves to high ground, wait for the walkers to get into the barn, and then light the petrol, thereby setting the walkers on fire.

This demonstrates that "live" walkers (as opposed to "dead" ones that have been shot/stabbed in the head, etc. as discussed above by bitmask and Andres F.) appear to be just as flammable as ordinary live humans.

Comment: PS Wasn't sure if my reference to the other answers posted also constitutes a spoiler (as it refers obliquely to certain incidents), if I should put that in the spoiler box as well let me know and I'll rectify...

Answer (score 1):

In the TV series, in the season 2 episode titled "**Nebraska**":

> Most of the walkers from the barn, except for Sophia and Hershel's relatives, get burned instead of buried, because they were too many to bury. One of the characters explicitly says "We bury the ones we love, and burn the rest".

Therefore the walkers are flammable, just like human corpses.

Answer (score 0):

and further, in the season 3 episode Prey

> A number of trapped walkers are doused with gasoline and set alight. Someone returning to the scene the following day finds several of them still groaning and moving, but burned to a crisp and unable to stand upright (presumably their leg muscles have been burned away)

Comment: That's gross!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that we can safely say that zombies on The Walking Dead TV show are in fact flammable. They do not however appear to be affected by the flames in the same way that the living are. They appear to not feel pain in the same way which is consistent with all other injuries. The [Season 5 premier](http://www.amctv.com/shows/the-walking-dead/tag/season-5/episode-1) airing October 12, 2014 demonstrates this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Only knowing a little about decaying meat I would think that they would be more flammable due to the phosphine gas prouduced from the rotting flesh... I think one of the first things I will try to find is a flame thrower when the Z.A. happens. Much more effective than a crossbow. Just saying...